# Notepad++ replace exponent values with zero

Tags: notepad++

I use the notepad++ (7.8.1) regular expression \d+.\d{2}\K\d+ to change the decimal point of values in a big text file. This takes a bit of time and normally works well, but when finished I got errors importing the file. It is a big text file (way to big for excel) with 3 columns, tab delimeted. e.g. 266051.07799999998 7617493.20100000035 -15.2008895874023438

Turns out, some of the values were written as exponential values(e.g. -5.992e-06) and didn't convert.

Is there a fast way to convert this text to plain 0

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61401472/edit) and add sample lines and expected result. Also, [don't cross post](https://superuser.com/q/1545176/763386), delete one of the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(-?\d+\.\d+e[+-]?\d+)|\d\.\d\d\K\d+`
- Replace with: `(?{1}0:)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  (             # group 1
    -?            # optional minus sign
    \d+           # 1 or more digits
    \.            # decimal point
    \d+           # 1 or more digits
    e             # exp
    [+-]?         # optional sign
    \d+           # 1 or more digits
  )             # end group 1
|             # OR
\d\.\d\d        # a digit, a dot, 2 digits
\K              # forget them
\d+             # 1 or more digits
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?{1}       # if group 1 exists, exponantial value
  0           # replace with 0
  :         # else, nothing
)           # end conditional
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. This explains quite a bit of the  parameters used in notepad++also. Thanks again?

Comment: @Zoner: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)